# Feature to allow for automatic uninstallation of application upon updating app

Tags: c#, installshield, windows

I am creating a Windows application (x32) using ISLE (InstallShield Limited Edition).

Often when I provide a new version of my application, the user has to manually go to "Uninstall a program" in order to remove previous version of application before he can perform a reinstallation.

How can I remove this requirement.. by say automatically uninstalling existing versions in case they exist when the user launches a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

You remove this hassle by properly implementing what is called a "Major Upgrade".  The newer version will perform an uninstall/reinstall under the covers and if the new install fails it'll rollback to the original version.